# How to color one row with one color without border?

Tags: html, css

I have this table:

```
 <table class="custom-table">
      <tr>
          <td>231232131</td>
           <td>INTERNATIONAL FEDERATION O</td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

What i want is to have row with one color for example `#eee;`

Right now when i add

```
tr{
 background:#eee;
}
```

I have gray color for row but between td i have white space between, but if i add on :

```
table{
background:#eee
}
```

Then i dont have space between tr. Any suggestion?

Comment: Off the top of my head, maybe [`border-collapse: collapse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) on `table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the [border-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) property to the table.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse):

> The border-collapse CSS property specifies whether a table's borders are separated or collapsed. In the separated-border model, adjacent cells each have their own distinct borders. In the collapsed-border model, adjacent cells share borders.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr {
  background: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<table class="custom-table">
  <tr>
    <td>231232131</td>
    <td>INTERNATIONAL FEDERATION O</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```